# There's no zeppelin.livy.principal in Ambari Zeppelin Service configuration with HDP 3 stack installed

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hdpi, livy, hortonworks-dataflow

According to this [doc](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/configuring-zeppelin/content/configuring_livy_on_an_ambari-managed_cluster.html), i should find `zeppelin.livy.principal` in config of `zeppelin` or `spark2`, but there's no such option there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property is found via the zeppelin UI:

Log in as a user with admin privileges; on the zeppelin UI -> Config -> interpreters -> pick your current livy interpreter or create a new one -> here you will notice the `zeppelin.livy.principal` property.